# PHP Undefined variable ldap

Tags: php, ldap

I'm having some trouble while developing the activation page of my site...

I have 3 pages, config.inc.php, functions.inc.php and activate.php

On activate.php I require config.inc.php and include functions.inc.php
On functions.inc.php I also require config.inc.php

But I have this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ldap in D:\xampp\htdocs\pap\inc\functions.inc.php on line 109

Fatal error: Call to a member function getRepository() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\pap\inc\functions.inc.php on line 109
```

ldap variable is define on config.inc.php:

```
$ldap = new LdapManager($config);
```

The function on functions.inc.php

```
use LdapTools\Object\LdapObjectType;
function ativar_conta($hash)
{
    // First get the user object via a repository.
    $repository = $ldap->getRepository(LdapObjectType::USER);
    $user = $repository->findOneByUsername($login);

    // Make sure the user account is set to enabled.
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    // Set their password to never expire.
    $user->setPasswordNeverExpires(true);

    try 
    {
        $ldap->persist($user);
        echo'teste';
        return true;
    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        echo "Error modifying user! ".$e->getMessage();

        return false;
    }
}
```

This are my files: [link](https://pastebin.com/egcaKXUL)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have setup the files to import, try putting it into function

```
function ativar_conta($hash, ldap) {}
```

On activate.php make sure you have config.inc.php and include functions.inc.php in the right order so you are not calling one file which has dependencies before the other.

Without seeing the rest of the pages, I cant really comment on your question.

Comment: Looked over your code. I think you are not importing it into the function, thats why its yelling at you since it cannot see the variable. Try my suggestion in the answer above

Comment: Glad that helped!